# Getting error as "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'"

Tags: python-3.x

I am running a python code in in my local. While executing, it is giving me error as

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
import sklearn as sl
df =pd.read_csv(r'F:\Data science\house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques\train.csv')
df.set_index('Id')
df1=df.drop(['PoolQC','Fence'],axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.to_csv(r'F:\Data science\house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques\df_t1.csv')
```

Expecting to save a new file with a name in csv where the 2 columns are droped

Comment: Odd. It is saying that `df == None` at `df.to_csv()` but not at `df.set_index()` or `df.drop()`. Please post the entire error message. Maybe you typed `df1.to_csv(...)`?

Comment: I re run the code. But it didn't gave any error. It executed successfully